# Getting clientHeight from a react-reason DOM ref

Tags: dom, reason, reason-react

I'm accessing a `reason-react` DOM reference in order to ascertain client height.

Unfortunately `clientHeight` doesn't seem to be part of the `ref` API. So this fails:

```ml
ref
  -> React.Ref.current
  -> Js.Nullable.toOption
  -> Belt.Option.map(this => {
    React.Ref.clientHeight(this);
});
```

`The value clientHeight can't be found in React.Ref`.

Is there a way to extract the height of a component from the ref?

The ref was acquired from a div.

Comment: A ref can hold any kind of value. How did you acquire it? If you got it using `ReactDOMRe.Ref.domRef` you'll get a `Dom.element` and can use `Element.clientHeight` from `bs-webapi`

Comment: Added the clarification - your answer worked so I'll accept it if you're able to post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you acquired the ref from either `ReactDOMRe.Ref.domRef` or `ReactDOMRe.Ref.callbackDomRef`, you will receive a `Dom.element` and can use `Element.clientHeight` from [`bs-webapi`](https://github.com/reasonml-community/bs-webapi-incubator):

```
open Webapi.Dom;

ref
  -> React.Ref.current
  -> Js.Nullable.toOption
  -> Belt.Option.map(Element.clientHeight);
```

Comment: Can't the client height of a dom ref be extracted without bs-webapi ?

Comment: @a-c-sreedhar-reddy Sure, you can either create a binding to it yourself, or you can cast it to a `Js.t({..})` with `ReactDom.domElementToObj` to be able to access it using `ref##clientHeight`. Although I wouldn't recommend the latter as it throws type safety out the window.